# A group algebra isomorphism problem

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

What are the groups $G$ and fields $\Bbb K$ for which $\Bbb K[G]\cong\Bbb K^{|G|}$ holds?

For example $\Bbb R[\Bbb F_2^n]\cong\Bbb R^{2^n}$ holds.

Comment: As the group ring is identified with the set ${\mathbb K}^{(G)}$ which is the set oif maps from $G$ to $\mathbb K$ with finite support, the answer is: this is the case if and only if the group is finite.

Comment: @Anton: if you want an isomorphism as algebras this is not enough.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: What is the algebra structure on ${\mathbb K}^G$ when $G$ is not finite?

Comment: @Anton: pointwise multiplication.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is true iff $G$ is finite and abelian, the characteristic of $K$ does not divide $G$, and $K$ has all $n^{th}$ roots of unity whenever $G$ has an element of order $n$. Hopefully it is clear why $G$ must be finite and abelian. The characteristic and root of unity conditions follow from writing $G$ as a product of cyclic groups and applying the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Yes sorry I missed about all roots of unity. So is this good enough for algebra isomorphism?

Comment: @Arul: yes, that's what I'm claiming.

Comment: Oops yes I didn't say what I meant. I'll rewrite the comment, It' only a minor point anyway, but might as well say it right.

Comment: (Corrected): I suppose you could simplify the statement a bit: by stating that the field should have n distinct roots of unity whenever $G$ has an element of order $n$, you could omit the statement about the characteristic ( which would be implied by the other conditions).

Comment: Sure, but might as well make the characteristic hypothesis explicit for readability.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is $\Bbb C[\Bbb F_p^n]\cong\Bbb C^{p^n}$ isomorphism unique? what is the map?

Comment: @Student: it depends on what you mean by "unique." This algebra has automorphisms, and composing such an isomorphism with those automorphisms gives other, different isomorphisms. The sense in which this isomorphism is *natural* is that, more generally, if $A$ is a finite abelian group then we have natural isomorphisms $\mathbb{C}[A] \cong \mathbb{C}^{A^{\vee}}$ where $A^{\vee}$ denotes the Pontryagin dual.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan One way to do this is take $\sum\alpha a$ where $a\in\Bbb F_p^n$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ and map it to $p^n$ dimension vector which has $\alpha$ in $a$th coordinate interpreted as integer now. This is just canonical but has no interesting combinatorial or any other structure. Is there any other interesting structural map?

Comment: @Student: that's not the map I have in mind; the isomorphism I have in mind is an algebra isomorphism. For example, if $A$ is a finite cyclic group it's given by the discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is there an easy reference with explicit formulas for engineering background?